# Pass Parent Prop to Children reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Legend, which contains multiple Legend.Items children. I'm having a problem where currently `onClick` it is possible to deselect all of the Legend Items which has consequences that I'd like to avoid. Is it possible to set some sort of `onClick` handler in the `Legend` component that can have some state `clicked` and check whether there are `n - 1` legend items "selected/faded", `n` being the total number of legend items? I looked at the JSX Spread Attributes, but because I'm using `{this.props.children}`, I'm not sure how to use them or if they would work in this context.

I also took a look at this blogpost (http://jaketrent.com/post/send-props-to-children-react/), but it looked a bit hacky to me and I thought there might be a more conventional way. I'm new to ReactJS so if I need to provide more context, let me know!

MY CODE:

**LEGEND.JSX**

```
var React = require('react');
var cn = require('classnames');

// Have legend hold state about how many clicked
var Legend = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { clicked: 0 }
  },

  render: function () {
    console.log(this.props.children);

    return (
      <ul className="legend inline-list">
        {this.props.children}
      </ul>
    );
  },
});

Legend.Item = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { hover: false, clicked: false };
  },

  handleMouseOver: function () {
    this.setState({ hover: true });
    this.props.mouseOver(this.props.name);
  },

  handleMouseOut: function () {
    this.setState({ hover: false });
    this.props.mouseOut(this.props.name);
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    if (this.state.clicked) {
      this.setState({ clicked: false });
      this.props.click(this.props.name);
    } else {
      this.setState({ clicked: true });
      this.props.click(this.props.name);
    };
  },

  render: function () {
    var swatchClasses = cn({ 'swatch': true, 'legend-item-fade': this.state.hover, 'c3-legend-item-hidden': this.state.clicked })
    var spanClasses = cn({ 'legend-item-fade': this.state.hover, 'c3-legend-item-hidden': this.state.clicked })

    return (
      <li className="legend-item">
        <i className={swatchClasses}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseOver}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseOut}
          style={{ "backgroundColor": this.props.color }}></i>
        <span className={spanClasses}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
          onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseOver}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseOut}>
          {this.props.name}
        </span>
      </li>
    );
  },
});

module.exports = {
  Legend: Legend,
};
```

**RESPONSE.JSX RENDER FUNCTION**

```
<Legend>
  {newColumns.map(function (column) {
    return (
      <Legend.Item name={column.name}
        color={column.color}
        click={this.onLegendClick}
        mouseOut={this.onLegendMouseOut}
        mouseOver={this.onLegendMouseOver}/>
    );
  }.bind(this))}
</Legend>
```

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle (use the [React Base Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)) to demonstrate what your code does, and what you'd like it to do?

Comment: Can't you just pass an argument to your click handler specifying it is a select/deselection click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best and simplest way is to use callbacks.

In `Legend` recreate the components from the children, augmenting their props with a callback to `Legend`:

```
let legendItems = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => 
    React.cloneElement(child, { updateLegendCounter: this.updateLegend})
);
```

The callback in `Legend` is something like this:

```
updateLegend() {
    this.setState({clicked: clicked + 1})
}
```

And finally, in your render method, you discriminate when

```
if (this.state.clicked === children.length-1)
```

Also, I would pass the initial state of `clicked` as a prop to the `Item` element. In this way it becomes really easy to select/deselect all.